# How to get Reader and ReaderT to work together

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm using the ReaderT Monad transformer to propagate my configuration data from my main function through several functions performing IO. The ultimate function that will need the data doesn't perform any IO. I have this working solution :

```hs
import Control.Monad.Reader

type Configuration = String

funNoIO :: Reader Configuration String
funNoIO = do
    config <- ask
    return $ config ++ "!"

funIO :: ReaderT Configuration IO String
funIO = do
    config <- ask
    return $ runReader funNoIO config

main :: IO ()
main = do
    c <- runReaderT funIO "configuration"
    print c
```

But it forces me to retrieve the configuration in the `funIO` function where I don't need it.

I modified it like this :

```hs
funIO' :: ReaderT Configuration IO String
funIO' = do
    v <- funNoIO
    return v
```

but it doesn't compile and I'm getting this error :

```
Couldn't match type ‘ReaderT Configuration Identity String’
              with ‘Identity (ReaderT Configuration IO String)’
Expected type: Identity (ReaderT Configuration IO String)
  Actual type: Reader Configuration String
In the first argument of ‘runIdentity’, namely ‘funNoIO’
In a stmt of a 'do' block: v <- runIdentity funNoIO
```

Is it possible to propagate my configuration data to a pure function without retrieving it in the intermediary IO functions?

EDIT

I parameterised my functions but I still can't perform an IO action in the `funIO'` function. For example :

```hs
getMessage :: IO String
getMessage = do
    return "message"

funIO' :: MonadIO m => ReaderT Configuration m String
funIO' = do
    m <- getMessage
    v <- funNoIO
    return $ v ++ m
```

is giving me the following error :

```
Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘ReaderT Configuration m’
Expected type: ReaderT Configuration m String
Actual type: IO String
```

EDIT 2

I got it, I just needed to use `liftIO` :

```hs
getMessage :: IO String
getMessage = do
    return "message"

funIO' :: MonadIO m => ReaderT Configuration m String
funIO' = do
    m <- liftIO getMessage
    v <- funNoIO
    return $ v ++ m
```

Comment: Yes. Just let the compiler infer the most general type for each function. If you do that, `funIO'` compiles. Or even `funNoIO :: Monad m => ReaderT Configuration m String` will work - since you never manipulate the inner monad, it makes sense that it could be anything. Then a sensible type for `funIO'` is `MonadIO m => ReaderT Configuration m String` - the MonadIO constraint would come from any uses of `liftIO` inside the definition.

Comment: You can keep funNoIO as plain Reader if, when you come to mix it with `IO`-dependent things you use the `mmorph` approach https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph-1.0.4 , writing `hoist generalize funNoIO` . The example in the documents uses a `State/StateT` example that is exactly parallel to yours. `hoist` has many other applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the type of `funNoIO` and `funIO` to be parameterised over the monad type since they aren't used:

```
funNoIO :: Monad m => ReaderT Configuration m String
funIO' :: Monad m => ReaderT Configuration m String
```

to fix the compiler error, then you can change `main` to:

```
main = do
    c <- runReaderT funIO' "configuration"
    print c
```

Comment: You can also make their type signature `MonadReader Configuration m => m String`

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use the `reader` method of `MonadReader` together with `runReader`:

```
funIO = reader $ runReader funNoIO
```

`reader . runReader` converts from the pure `Reader` monad to a more general `MonadReader` instance.